# C# ComboBox for IP addresses

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, windows-forms-designer

I need a custom combo box that holds IP addresses. I have a custom control that holds an IP address(that actually is a panel with 4 textboxes). I already tried adding other controls to a normal combo box, such as a button and a textbox. I get no exceptions but I would expect to see the item in the drop-down list, instead i get a blank line for each item.

My first thoughts about this would be to extend the ComboBox control. What would you suggest?

Comment: It's much easier in WPF. Consider it, if applicable.

Answer (score 0):

A combo box is basically a textbox and a (usually) button-activated listbox combined for convenience.  If it's not convenient you could implement your own dropdown functionality.  Put a button next to your textboxes that display a listbox and when an item is selected from the listbox, put the values in the appropriate textboxes.  In other words, don't try to extend the combo box, try to re-construct a similar control based on similar components.

Answer (score 0):

It's not too difficult to override the `ComboBox` so I suppose you could create a custom `ComboBox` to show your own control that would be a container showing multiple of your IP Address controls.

Here's a [blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2006/10/13/custom-combobox.aspx) by [JaredPar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23283/jaredpar) showing how to get started, just replace the m_form with your own custom container control.

Answer (score 0):

You can hold the ip-addresses in a listbox, even in a combobox or what ever you want. Do not forget how your coding is, if you have an oop based tcp-socket program than no cross thread exception will be thrown. the codes shall be like ListBox.Items.Add(ipaddress) or ComboBox.Items.Add(ipaddress) ...

In controls you may hold only the ip-addresses, if you want to store the socket objects use Dictionary ... Your answer is not clear, so i've answered on possibly situations.